# How does C++ do bitwise "or" operations on negative numbers?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

When I give to a variable such value: `e = 17|-15;` , I  get -15 as an answer after compiling.I can't understand what arithmetic c++ uses. How does it perform a bit-wise OR operation on negative decimals?

Comment: 2's complement....?

Comment: Technically, I think it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: It probably does the `OR` on the value's plain two's-complement data..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Technically, though you'd be hard-pressed to find an exception.

Comment: I performed the operation on their 2's complement representations but i don't get -15 anyway

Comment: @chris, practically, yes. But do you mean now or in the future? :)

Comment: @user1978522 Really? Then you did it wrong ;)

Comment: If you didn't get -15 as an answer, then you did something wrong. Maybe you didn't convert to two's-complement form correctly. Or maybe you had some bits misaligned.

Comment: this is such a fastest gun question

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, according to the C++ standard (in 3.9.1.7) it is implementation dependent to support architectures that are not necessarily 2's complement. However, every architecture in the past few decades has been 2's complement-based (since it simplifies the hardware) so it is more than a safe bet.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Now, I guess. What'd coming in the future? O_o

Comment: @chris, well, nobody knows, and that's why the C++ language leaves the binary representation of signed integers for the implementation to decide. I guess my point was that almost all of them may be using two's complement now, but who knows about later?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's just doing the operation on the binary representations of your numbers.  In your case, that appears to be [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

```
 17 -> 00010001
-15 -> 11110001
```

As you can see, the bitwise `OR` of those two numbers is still `-15`.

In your comments above, you indicated that you tried this with the two's complement representations, but you must have done something wrong.  Here's the step by step:

```
 15 ->  00001111      // 15 decimal is 00001111 binary
-15 -> ~00001111 + 1  // negation in two's complement is equvalent to ~x + 1
-15 ->  11110000 + 1  // do the complement
-15 ->  11110001      // add the 1
```

Comment: Can I know any example where we need to use bitwise operations on negative numbers? I thought bitwise is usually on unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 7):

It does OR operations on negative numbers the same way it does so on positive numbers. The numbers are almost certainly represented in two's-complement form, which gives you these values:

```
 17 = 0000000000010001
-15 = 1111111111110001
```

As you can see, all the bits of 17 are already set in −15, so the result of combining them is again −15.

Answer (score 4):

A bitwise or with a negative number works JUST like a bitwise or with a positive number. The bits in one number are ored with the bits in the other number. How your processor represents negative numbers is a different matter. Most use something called "two's complement", which is essentially "invert the number and add 1".

So, if we have, for simplicity, 8 bit numbers:

```
15 is            00001111
Inverted we get  11110000
Add one          11110001

17 is            00010001

Ored together    11110001
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   17 = b00010001
  -15 = b11110001 <--- 2s complement
| -15 = b11110001
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to looks at how the bits work

Basically, if either number has a `1` in a particular spot, than the result will also have a `1`

```
-15       : 11110001 (two's complement)
17        : 00010001
-15 | 17  : 11110001
```

as you can see, the result is the same as `-15`

Comment: You're a very pretty two, aren't you.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `|` is a "bitwise `OR`" operator, meaning that every bit in the target is computed as the `OR`-combination of the corresponding bits in the two operands. This means, that a bit in the result is `1` if *any* of the two bits in the numbers at the same positions are `1`, otherwise `0`.

Clearly, the result depends on the binary representation of the numbers which again depends on the platform.

Almost all platforms use the **Two's complement**, which can be thought as a circle of unsigned numbers, in which negative numbers are just in the opposite direction than positive numbers and "wrap around" the circle.

Unsigned integers:

[image]

Signed integers:

[image]

The calculation of your example is as follows.

```
 17:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001
-15:   11111111 11111111 11111111 11110001
------------------------------------------
-15:   11111111 11111111 11111111 11110001
```

Comment: Depends on the compiler or the platform?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I don't know for sure. If there is a platform which supports multiple different representations, there could exist two different compilers using two different representations. However, I don't think that such a platform exists.

Comment: I think the C ABI would impose a consistent representation on any one platform tbh.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I changed it to "platform".