# bitwise and on negative integer is different from bitwise and on positive integer

Tags: bitwise-and

I have found several thread regarding bitwise operation on negative integer, and I found one that is pretty helpful, it says that bitwise operation on negative integer is the same as positive integer, but when I tested -4 & -5 in 3 different languages ( C++, Object( FPC )-Pascal, and Dlang ) they all outputted -8, meanwhile 4 & 5 is 4, why are different ?

Comment: "*I found one that is pretty helpful, it says that bitwise operation on negative integer is the same as positive integer*" - how is that helpful when it's wrong?

Comment: it did say bitwise or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326900/how-does-c-do-bitwise-or-operations-on-negative-numbers

Comment: Bitwise and is "preserve all of the 1 bits that are in common between the two inputs, set all remaining bits to 0". Depending on your notion of *sameness*, then yes, it acts identically for positive and negative numbers. But *what that means* depends on how *bits* are interpreted as numbers.

Comment: so, in the case of the three language that I mentioned, how are they interpreted as numbers ?

Comment: Almost certainly, all using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: well, for example in 8 bit, I thought it was like 5 == 00000101, and -5 == 10000101, apparently it is not

Comment: That would be [Sign and magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation). You're unlikely to encounter a system using that these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not required by most languages (C and C++ and Pascal definitely don't; I don't know about D) essentially all modern computers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for integers.

```
  ..0 0100 = positive 4  
& ..0 0101 = positive 5  
= ..0 0100 = positive 4

  ..1 1100 = negative 4  
& ..1 1011 = negative 5  
= ..1 1000 = negative 8
```